# Releasing Unused properties in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, properties, dealloc

I have this property synthesized and declared in my class 'ClassA'

```
@interface ClassA
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NameFieldCell* nameCell;
@end
```

I know that the rule says that the nameCell property should be released in my dealloc method when it is declared with retain|copy|...

However, 'ClassA' gets instantiated lazily and sometimes the nameCell property is not even used, which means that I don't use its setter method nor access it nor retain it explicitly.

Should I still be calling [nameCell release] in my dealloc method? I find it difficult to understand that I should be releasing something that is not even initialized. And since it is not initialized, the reference counter is 0 and makes no sense to release it? Or is nameCell somehow retained automatically when instantiating 'ClassA' even if I am not making use of it?

Comment: Yes, you should still release it in your dealloc method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C, the memory allocated by `alloc` for a class is initialized to all-bits-zero on allocation (and then the `isa` ivar is set), which results in `nameCell`'s backing ivar being set to `nil` by default. And since it is not an error to send a message to `nil` in Objective-C (the message is just ignored), you are free to just call `[nameCell release]` without worrying about whether `nameCell` was ever set.

Answer (score 3):

If `nameCell` is nil, then `[nameCell release]` has no effect. This makes it easy to cover both cases, so yes, you should release it in your dealloc method.

That or start using [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), and you won't have to worry about it.